# What is the logical xor operator in java?

Tags: java, boolean-logic, xor

In java, there is a logical OR operator (`||`) and a logical AND operator (`&&`).  Is there a [logical XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_XOR) operator?  I tried `^^` but it does not work.

Comment: What would a logical xor do? There is a bitwise xor which is ^.

Comment: A logical xor (A logical_xor B) is pretty much just `A != B`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The logical XOR operator does exist in Java and is spelled `^`.**

To get the terminology right, in Java:

- `&`, `|` and `^` are called *bitwise* or *logical* operators, depending on the types of their arguments;
- `&&` and `||` are called *conditional* operators.

For details, see [JLS § 15.22. Bitwise and Logical Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22) onwards.

There is no direct equivalent for `&&` and `||` for [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). The only reason `&&` and `||` exist as separate operators from `&` and `|` is their [short-circuiting behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (that's why they're called "conditional"), and XOR cannot be short-circuited.

Comment: Interesting. The table at _The Java™ Tutorials_ on [Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) refers to "logical operators" as distinct from "bitwise operators", yet [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) refers to "conditional operators" as you say.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the conflict. Actually I think that "logical operator" means that Boolean values are being compared. Thus the condition operators are logical operators, and the bitwise operators can also be used as logical operators. That's why the JLS says "Bitwise and Logical Operators" when referring to `&`, `|`, and `^`. So I don't think it would be incorrect to refer to `&&` and `||` (the conditional operators) as logical operators as well.